# multipart HTTP request with microsoft graph javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph JavaScript SDK to create a page in OneNote with images, which OneNote requires a multipart request for. I've created a `FormData` object with all the data I'm trying to send.

The request goes through when I send it up myself as follows:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer" + token);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  //Call a function when the state changes
  if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
    // Request finished. Do processing here.
  } else {
    // handle case
  }
};
// dataToSend = FormData object containing data
// (as Blobs), including the page HTML in a
// "Presentation" part as specified
xhr.send(dataToSend);
```

However, since I'm using the Graph SDK to make all my other requests, I'm wondering if there's a way to do the multipart request with the SDK as well. So far, this is what I've tried:

```
this.client
  .api(pagesURL)
  .version("beta")
  .header("Content-Type", "text/html")
  .post(dataToSend);
```

Investigating the request in Fiddler shows that the request body contains `[object, Object]`, not the data formatted as a multipart request. Any help on how to get the FormData object into the request properly using the SDK/ guidance on whether this is possible would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
this.client
  .api("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/notes/sections/{Section ID}/pages")
  .header("Content-Type", "application/xhtml+xml")
  .header("boundary", "MyPartBoundary")
  .post(dataToSend);
```

This snippet was adapted from the multi-part unit test used by the SDK itself. You can find that test at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/spec/types/OneNote.ts

Answer (score 0):

Update the microsoft-graph-client to latest version and try something like this.

```
    const HTMLPageContent = 
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>A page with rendered images</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>Here is an image uploaded as <b>binary data</b>:</p>
            <img src="name:imageBlock1" alt="an image on the page" />
        </body>
    </html>`;

    let sectionId = "<Your_OneNote_Page_Section_Id>";
    let formData = new FormData();
    let htmlBlob = new Blob([HTMLPageContent], {
        type: "text/html"
    });
    formData.append("Presentation", htmlBlob);
    formData.append("imageBlock1", file);
    client
        .api(`/me/onenote/sections/${sectionId}/pages`)
        .post(formData)
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
            return Promise.resolve();
        });
```